# Access Global variable from drool function in the file.drl

Tags: java, drools

When I'm trying to access the global variable from the drool function I got an exception:

[image]

> threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException:
> Unable to get KieModule, Errors Existed: Error Messages: Message
> [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=insuranceperiod.drl,
> line=-1, column=0   text=Error importing :
> 'KieRule.AddString.addString'] Message [id=2, kieBase=defaultKieBase,
> level=ERROR, path=insuranceperiod.drl, line=15, column=0 text=[
> function addStringaddString (line:15): stringList cannot be resolved
> ]]

the code is below:

- **Java Code**

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
droolSession.setGlobal("stringList",stringList)
droolSession.fireAllRules();
```

- **drl Code**

```
global java.util.List stringList;

function void addString(String s){
    stringList.add(s);
}
```

Try to access global variable inside drool function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a DRL global from the body of a DRL function.

The rationale is the following: DRL functions are equivalent to Java `static` methods. A DRL global can be considered analogous to an instance field (as you can see in your snippet, you set the global value on a Session instance, not a KBase). Similarly to Java, you cannot access instance fields from a static method.

If you tried to define `static void addString(String s) {...}` as a static method in Java and then to use it from the RHS, you would have faced similar issue: the definition of the static method do not have scope access to your `stringList` instance.

You can always refactor your code to comply with scope visibility and address your need in a different way.